# Rails 5, Ajax - calling a function on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This is a partial for one item. Many items are being displayed in one page.

**_line_item.html.er**b:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <tr data-line-item-id='<%= line_item.id %>', id='row-<%= line_item.id %>', class="line_item_cart">
      <td data-th="Product">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td data-th="Price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.product.price) %></td>
      <td data-th="Quantity">
        <%= line_item.quantity %>
      </td>
      <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center" class="subtotal">
        <%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price, :unit => "€", separator: ",", format: "%n %u") %></td>
      <td class="actions" data-th="">
        <td><%= link_to "-", decrease_line_item_path(product_id: line_item.product), remote: true %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "+", increase_line_item_path(product_id: line_item.product), remote: true %></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you see, if user decrease number of same type items I am calling Ajax, through `remote: true`.

**line_items_controller.rb**:

```
  def decrease
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.remove_product(product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.js
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**cart.rb**:

```
  def remove_product(product)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
    if current_item.quantity >= 1
      current_item.quantity -= 1
    else
      current_item.destroy
    end
    current_item
  end
```

**decrease.js.erb**:

```
var i = $('.delete_item').closest('tr').find('.item_quantity').html();
if (i > 0){
  $('#row-<%= @line_item.id %> td:nth-child(3)').html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>')
  $('#row-<%= @line_item.id %> td:nth-child(4)').html(
    "<%= number_to_currency(@line_item.total_price, :unit => "€", separator: ",", format: "%n %u") %>")
  }
else {
      $('#row-<%= @line_item.id %> td').fadeOut();
}
```

Increasing / decreasing goes well, but item row doesn't disappear if 0 is reached. As you can see from `decrease.js.erb` I am trying to `fadeOut` it, but it is not going as expected. It fades off, but only if I start with the first item from the list... Can anyone help with this?

Thanks for help `if` help

**UPDATE**

Sharing my results so far...

From my findings I assume I should use callbacks here, to check if the number of quantity is 1 (if so - fadeOut would be very welcome). So I am trying something like this (but very afraid to make any silly syntax error)

**decrease.js.rb**

```
function getData(){
  return $.ajax({
    qnt: $('<%= @line_item.quantity %>'),
    row: $('#row-<%= @line_item.id %>')
  });
}

function handleData(qnt) {
  if ((qnt.match(/\d+/)) > 1) {
    $('#row-<%= @line_item.id %> td:nth-child(3)').html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>')
    $('#row-<%= @line_item.id %> td:nth-child(4)').html(
      "<%= number_to_currency(@line_item.total_price, :unit => "€", separator: ",", format: "%n %u") %>")
    }
    else {
      $('row').fadeOut();
    }
}

getData().done(handleData);
```

Last example decreases quantities, but doesn't fades Out if 1 is reached. If I could check it in browser debugger would be great, but it doesent recognise for ex. this `$('#row-<%= @line_item.id %>')`. I think that this might be a glitch.

I know that this way might be not the best way, but I am not greed. I will eat it bite by bite. Please help and share any of your thoughts..